# Memory needed by android VM exceeds driver limit

Tags: java, android

Im trying to debug an android communication app that allows communication with multiple users. I wanted to try it with 5 phones.

I only have 1 real phone, so i thought of running 4 android emulators simultaneously from android studio to see if i can get 5 phones to chat together.

After i run two emulators everything fine, but when i try to start the third emulator i got this message.

```
Cannot launch AVD in emulator.
Output:
Hax is enabled
The memory needed by this VM exceeds the driver limit.
Hax ram_size 0x60000000
HAX is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode.
qtest is not supported under Windows
```

My computer has 24 GB of physical RAM so i think maybe it should be able to handle 4 emulators?

Anybody knows how to bypass this problem so i can run 4 of them?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a new device (emulator) in the Android Studio AVD, click the "New Hardware" button and then locate the "Memory" line. You can edit pre-existing devices by clicking the pencil icon and then clicking the "Advanced Settings" button, and locating "Memory and Storage."

Try lowering the amount of RAM required for each emulator (perhaps 512MB/1024MB instead of 2048MB?). Make sure that the memory limit for HAXM (set during installation) is the same size as the total memory allocated to your devices/emulators!

**How to set your HAXM memory limit:**
Control Panel -> Programs -> Programs and Features -> Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager -> Change -> Set manually

Note that re-installing HAXM (perhaps from the command line) will allow you to change the memory limit as well.